# Reorder records using sql query (rewrite into single query)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `sliders` table.

```
+----+-----+---------+
| id | pos | content |
+----+-----+---------+
| 1  | 0   | image   |
+----+-----+---------+
| 2  | 1   | image   |
+----+-----+---------+
| 3  | 2   | video   |
+----+-----+---------+
| 4  | 3   | video   |
+----+-----+---------+
| 5  | 4   | image   |
+----+-----+---------+
```

**What I wanted this records to be is in the order of:**

1. Image
2. Video
3. ...everything else

Currently, I have a `pos` column meaning position. It is arranged by number in which 0 is the first and the largest is the last.

I need to rearrange it using a single query but currently, I am using 3 queries to do this.

First is: `UPDATE sliders SET pos = pos + 2`

That will return:

```
+----+-----+---------+
| id | pos | content |
+----+-----+---------+
| 1  | 2   | image   |
+----+-----+---------+
| 2  | 3   | image   |
+----+-----+---------+
| 3  | 4   | video   |
+----+-----+---------+
| 4  | 5   | video   |
+----+-----+---------+
| 5  | 6   | image   |
+----+-----+---------+
```

Then I will find the first video, and the first image to set them their position as first and second.

```
UPDATE sliders SET pos = 0 WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM sliders WHERE content='image')
UPDATE sliders SET pos = 1 WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM sliders WHERE content='video')
```

That will return:

```
+----+-----+---------+
| id | pos | content |
+----+-----+---------+
| 1  | 0   | image   |
+----+-----+---------+
| 2  | 2   | image   |
+----+-----+---------+
| 3  | 1   | video   |
+----+-----+---------+
| 4  | 5   | video   |
+----+-----+---------+
| 5  | 6   | image   |
+----+-----+---------+
```

I don't mind if there are gaps as long as it is in order.

The question is, is there any other way to do this, if possible a single query without gaps or anything?

**Expected output:**

```
+----+-----+---------+
| id | pos | content |
+----+-----+---------+
| 1  | 0   | image   |
+----+-----+---------+
| 2  | 2   | image   |
+----+-----+---------+
| 3  | 1   | video   |
+----+-----+---------+
| 4  | 3   | video   |
+----+-----+---------+
| 5  | 4   | image   |
+----+-----+---------+
```

If there is no other way, I guess I can stick with 3 queries.

Answer (score 1):

I Think this can't update single query, because we should know `min(pos)`, but `pos` should be updated.
And `mysql` can't use `with`.
So if you can make view, maybe it is possible.

This is view.
new_pos col is new position. (1. image, 2. video, and you don't mind if there are gaps...)

```
create view newSliders as (
select id,
       pos,
       case content when 'image' then case pos when (select min(pos) from sliders where content = 'image') then 0
                                               else pos+2
                                      end
                    when 'video' then case pos when (select min(pos) from sliders where content = 'video') then 1
                                               else pos++2
                                      end
       end as new_pos,
       content
  from sliders
)
```

and this is update single query.

```
update sliders
   set pos = (select new_pos from newSliders where id = sliders.id);
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Your statement "mysql cant use with" is not correct. mysql can use CTE (with), depending on the version.

Comment: I added a second version without the "with" clause.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you in sql server. You will have to adjust your over clause in mysql.

First create test data:

```
declare @t table(id int, pos int, content varchar(20))
insert @t values (1,0,'image')
,(2,1,'image')
,(3,2,'video')
,(4,3,'other')
,(5,4,'image')
select * from @t

id  pos content
1   0   image
2   1   image
3   2   video
4   3   other
5   4   image
```

Do the update using row_number

```
;with t as (
    select id, content, pos,
    row_number() over(order by case content when 'image' then 1 when 'video' then 2 else 3 end,id) rn
    from @t
)
update t set pos=rn
```

The result:

```
select * from @t

id  pos content
1   1   image
2   2   image
3   4   video
4   5   other
5   3   image
```

If you are at an old version of mysql that doesnt support CTEs, then this does the same thing:

```
update t set pos=p.rn
from @t t
join (
    select id, content, pos,
    row_number() over(order by case content when 'image' then 1 when 'video' then 2 else 3 end,id) rn
    from @t
) p on p.id=t.id
```